# Google Places search requests are duplicated lat&long data in gas_station type

Tags: google-places-api

Presumably I have found a mistake in issuing the query result Nearby Search Requests.

Lat & Long are duplicated after first element of Google answer.

As you can see below lat & long coordinates are exactly the same in this response (after 1 item json).

[image]

This error applies only to request `types=gas_station`.

Example of request: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=55.751729,37.618454&radius=1500&types=gas_station&sensor=false&key=YourAPIKeyHere`

Tell me please, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Please do not post your API key publicly as malicious users could steal your key and abuse the Places API with it which would link back to your account. I would recommend that you generate a new API Key in the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) under the API Access tab on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if your search for all these places on maps.google.com, they all contain approximate locations with the wording "Placement on map is approximate" indicating that google does not have the location data for these places, therefore this seems to be a data quality issue.

If you know the correct locations for these places, please submit a map or place edit by following the Google Maps help instructions to [Report a Problem with Google Maps](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162873) or to [Report a problem for a business listing](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171429).

Another alternative to edit Google maps and places is to submit an edit through [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) by following the [instructions](http://support.google.com/mapmaker/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1096110&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1ne8x7v2e648a&cbrank=1) from Google Map Maker Help.

Your edit will then appear after it has been reviewed and accepted.